# SQL Query For Counting Sequence of Days Based on a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that has `id`, `timestamp` and control value.

I need query for ids which has control value 0 for 4 days or more in sequence

```
TimeS   ID  Kontrol
2012-06-18  5457554F-E9A5-4312-8BA3-424B2333D0B7    1
2012-06-14  3FC4AC80-7D94-496A-92D0-22350CA3CEA9    1
2012-06-14  FE3C1872-0F13-48CC-A6C9-BBE0EAB07B9D    0
2012-06-13  FE3C1872-0F13-48CC-A6C9-BBE0EAB07B9D    0
2012-06-12  FE3C1872-0F13-48CC-A6C9-BBE0EAB07B9D    0
2012-06-11  FE3C1872-0F13-48CC-A6C9-BBE0EAB07B9D    0
```

It should return `FE3C1872-0F13-48CC-A6C9-BBE0EAB07B9` for example.

Comment: Im using MSSQL. Okey I will post some data

Comment: Do you think that this is good sample data? There are no records to show according to your definition.

Comment: I need just ID of consecutive rows with control 0. Yes its matter that 4 ID's same in the sample .They are consecutive for 4 days

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id
  FROM tableName t1
 WHERE t1.kontrol = 0
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM tableName t2
                WHERE t2.id = t1.id
                  AND t2.kontrol = 0
                  AND t2.timeS = t1.timeS + 1
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM tableName t3
                                WHERE t3.id = t2.id
                                  AND t3.kontrol = 0
                                  AND t3.timeS = t2.timeS + 1
                                  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                FROM tableName t4
                                               WHERE t4.id = t3.id
                                                 AND t4.kontrol = 0
                                                 AND t4.timeS = t3.timeS + 1)))
```

Comment: Not limited to sequential days

Comment: It does not ensure days in sequnce

Comment: @efe demir: Edited. Please try this new solution.

Comment: It seems, It is okey for 4 days but what about more

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM table t1
     INNER JOIN 
     table t2 ON t2.TimeS+1 days=t1.TimeS
     INNER JOIN 
     table t3 ON t3.TimeS+2 days=t1.TimeS
     INNER JOIN 
     table t4 ON t4.TimeS+3 days=t1.TimeS
WHERE t1.Control = 0 AND
      t2.Control = 0 AND
      t3.Control = 0 AND
      t4.Control = 0
```

Comment: Could you check the question again please

Comment: Query looks good to me, for your RDMS you may need to tweak the addition of days

Comment: You forgot to join on IDs as well, but something like this should work

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Times = DATEADD(dd,1,t1.TimeS)
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID AND t3.Times = DATEADD(dd,2,t1.TimeS)
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t4 ON t1.ID = t4.ID AND t4.Times = DATEADD(dd,3,t1.TimeS)
WHERE t1.Kontrol = 0 AND t2.Kontrol= 0 AND t3.Kontrol = 0 AND t4.Kontrol = 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select 
  id, 
  count(distinct TimeS) 
from 
  table1
where 
  kontrol=0
group by 
  id 
having 
  count(distinct TimeS) >= 4;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ea93/1)**

Comment: _"which has control value 0 **for 4 days or more** in sequence"_ So even if you would have taken the date into account, there should be no interruption with other control-values in these timespan.

Comment: TimeS are not consecutive in this query